# scipy ImportError: dlopen no suitable image found in Python 3

Tags: scipy, python-3.6

I have python 3.6, Mac OS X El Capitan.
I installed scipy by `pip install scipy`. But when I import scipy, I get the following error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/**init**.py in ()
>       116     del _NumpyVersion
>       117 
>   --> 118     from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
>       119 
>       120     from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback.py in ()
>   ----> 1 from . import _ccallback_c
>         2 
>         3 import ctypes
>         4 
>         5 PyCFuncPtr = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p).**bases**[0]
>
> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.cpython-36m-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

I don't get this error in Python2.

Comment: The successful import of `scipy` in Python 2 is independent of the import in Python 3.6, because each Python installation has its own installation of `scipy`.  The reported error "mach-o, but wrong architecutre" can be caused by having installed i386 `*.so` files as part of `scipy` (in the sense of [x86_32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I386)) binary distribution of `scipy` (i.e., containing Mach-O i386 `*.so` files), but having an x86_64 Python.

Comment: Also useful, regarding architectures (x86_64, i386, etc) is `file /path/to/python`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am the only one on earth to have this issue. Fortunately, I got it to work with endless attempts. In case someone in the future gets the same error, you can try this:`python -m pip install scipy`. I have no idea why `pip install scipy` doesn't work.

Comment: In general, `pip` and `python -m pip` could run different Python versions, and so different `pip`s. This can happen when the  first`python` in the `PATH` is another version of Python than the version of Python that corresponds to the first `pip` that is in the `PATH`. `which -a python` and `which -a pip` can give information about these files, as well as `python --version` and `pip --version`. Running different versions of `pip` when invoking `pip` and `python -m pip` does not seem though to explain the error reported in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I did find on MacOS 10.14.2 is that I had installed Scipy 1.1. After executing `python -m pip install scipy` I got Scipy 1.2 and get rid of "ImportError: dlopen".